# Problems with Site.Master and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

i'm trying to make my site master page (`views/shared/site.master`) strongly typed.

eg. Inherits="TestProject.Mvc.Views.Shared.Site"

I can't seem to get this work. Once i make the site.master page strongly, typed, Visual Studio seems to 'loose' what `<%= Html.XXX %>` is. Also, the page throws an error when i try to display the default index route.

The SiteMasterViewData class exists in the views/shared/ folder and has been included at the top of the master page via..

```
<%@ Import Namespace="TestProject.Mvc.Views.Shared"%>
```

Can this be done? is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Damn - found my own answer.

All masterpages in the ASP.NET MVC v1. need to inherit from:

```
<%@ Master 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

so if u want to strongly type it, you can do this.

```
<%@ Master 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<SiteMasterViewData>" %>
```

HTH's other peeps :)